# How to: fetch data from a site without doing a Denial of Service attack / know when there is knew data on a site

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webclient, ddos

I'm trying to fetch data from a site using httpwebrequest\webclient, so what im doing is sending a request to get the site's html every 30 secounds.

Whats is happenin is that the site is blocking me for a Denial of Service attack because i send too much request from the computer.

How can i know when there is new data on a site without fetching data every 30 secounds?

OR

How can i fetch data from a site every 30 secounds without getting blocked for Denial of Service attack?

ok so im adding some code:

```
public void DownloadFile(String remoteFilename, String localFilename)
{
            Stream remoteStream = null;
            Stream localStream = null;
            HttpWebRequest gRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(remoteFilename);
            gRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.1.8) Gecko/20100202 Firefox/3.5.8 GTBDFff GTB7.0";

            gRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            gRequest.Accept = " text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8, */*";
            gRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            gRequest.ContentType = @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded";


            #region CookieManagement
            if (gCookies != null && gCookies.Count > 0)
            {
                gRequest.CookieContainer.Add(gCookies);
            }

            HttpWebResponse gResponse;

            try{
                gResponse = (HttpWebResponse)gRequest.GetResponse();

                //check if the status code is http 200 or http ok

                if (gResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    remoteStream = gResponse.GetResponseStream();
                    localStream = File.Create(localFilename);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRead;

                    do
                    {
                        // Read data (up to 1k) from the stream
                        bytesRead = remoteStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                        // Write the data to the local file
                        localStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    } while (bytesRead > 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error!");
                    Application.Exit();
                }

                if (gResponse != null) gResponse.Close();
                if (remoteStream != null) remoteStream.Close();
                if (localStream != null) localStream.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                Application.Exit();
            }
            #endregion
        }
```

and in the timer:

```
DownloadFile("http://www.fxp.co.il/forumdisplay.php?f=2709", @"C:\tmph.html");
```

so this forum is a buy\sell forum, so what im trying to do is to get the forum html every 30 sec, check the html for number of unread "buy" posts using htmlagilitypack.

Comment: How often is the data actually changing?  How important is it that you get updates every 30 seconds (can you get it every minute, or two, or five?).

Comment: It's a forum so there is no constant time, it depands on the people

Comment: Do they have an RSS feed?  Many forums do.

Comment: I'll check but still even if the site was no forum how can you do it?

Comment: Even if there were a way to get around the DOS prevention, and I happened to know it, I wouldn't tell you, because they're stopping people from doing it for a reason.

Comment: Ok, so read my first question...

Comment: That's why I suggested RSS, that would be a potential solution.  It's not a general purpose solution though; there is no general purpose solution.

Comment: ok, but lets say how does a chat works? doeasn't it check the internet all the time for new messeges?

Comment: It depends on the chat.  In most situations you're sending information to the client, the client isn't pinging the server every second for updates.  In the event that you are pinging the server, the server is expecting the pinging and so won't have such restrictive DOS prevention.  The point here is that *this* server is actively trying to stop you from pinging it so often.  I'm not about to help you subvert that.  If the server doesn't have a problem being pinged every few seconds then that's entirely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a longer polling interval and do HEAD requests to avoid fetching the entire document. You can parse the header returned and only do the GET if it is different from the previous header.

Comment: can you give me some examples please?

Comment: HEAD requests are basically for saving bandwidth and allow you to save a few bytes by checking for new content before getting the whole thing. If there is a transfer threshold that's part of the blocking mechanism, it can help you avoid hitting that. Most search engine spiders that hit forums do so only two or three times a day and space their requests out over a few hours.

Comment: It's difficult to give a good example without knowing what you're really trying to do. I know you're trying to visit a forum, but why are you trying to visit so frequently? What are you really trying to accomplish? Also, post some of your existing code. People will have a lot more patience if you're clear about what you want and have shown some effort of your own.

Comment: k i have edited the post with the info you asked for, thanks for helping! :)